# Can't activate Nvidia GPU on Ubuntu 22.04 (WSL2)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda

#### Problem definition

I have been trying to use my mobile Quadro T1000 with cuda in pytorch, but pytorch use CPU whatever I do. I installed pytorch, GPU drivers and CUDA Toolkit.

If I run command I get nothing

```
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

Pytorch info:
torch.__version__: 1.13.0+cu117
torch.version.cuda: 11.7
torch.cuda.current_device(): 0
torch.cuda.is_available(): True

Windows 10 Pro 21H2

#### Extra info:

1. `lspci`

   3a66:00:00.0 3D controller: Microsoft Corporation Basic Render Driver
   4498:00:00.0 3D controller: Microsoft Corporation Basic Render Driver
2. `nvcc -V`

   nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
   Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
   Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
   Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
   Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
3. `nvidia-smi`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p5UE.png

4. `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-nvidia` - nothing
5. `dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver` - nothing
6. `uname -a`
   Linux CPR-5CD111 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
7. `inxi -G`

Graphics:
Device-1: Microsoft Basic Render Driver driver: dxgkrnl v: N/A
Device-2: Microsoft Basic Render Driver driver: dxgkrnl v: N/A
Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 145x14
Message: GL data unavailable in console. Try -G --display

8. `grep 10de /lib/udev/rules.d/*` - nothing
9. `dmesg | grep nvidia` - nothing
10. `dmesg | grep NV` - nothing

    ```
    def train(res_model, criterion, optimizer, train_dataloader, test_dataloader, NUM_EPOCH=15):
      for epoch in tqdm(range(NUM_EPOCH)):
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0.
        train_size = 0

        train_pred = 0.

        for imgs, labels in train_dataloader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            imgs = imgs.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()

            y_pred = model(imgs)

            loss = criterion(y_pred, labels)
            loss.backward()

            train_loss += loss.item()
            train_size += y_pred.size(0)
            train_loss_log.append(loss.data / y_pred.size(0))

            train_pred += (y_pred.argmax(1) == labels).sum()

            optimizer.step()
    ```

Comment: Since the GPU itself isn't *directly* exposed to WSL2, the output of most of those commands looks completely expected to me.  I'll try to explain more in an answer later (have to step away for a while and may not get back to it until tomorrow), but let's focus on your core problem -- *"but pytorch use CPU whatever I do."*  Can you provide some sample code?  Note also that installing GPU drivers and CUDA toolkit in Ubuntu is unnecessary -- All that should be required is a recent *Windows* NVIDIA driver -- WSL2 should do the rest of the virtualization/passthrough.

Comment: Also, can you provide your Windows version?  10 or 11?  Which build -- GPU compute requires 21H2 or later.  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to see:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/enabling-gpu-acceleration-on-ubuntu-on-wsl2-with-the-nvidia-cuda-platform#1-overview

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I removed some lines of code, it's just some part of code
def train(res_model, criterion, optimizer, train_dataloader, test_dataloader, NUM_EPOCH=15):
    for epoch in tqdm(range(NUM_EPOCH)):
        model.train()
        train_loss = 0.
        train_size = 0
        train_pred = 0
        for imgs, labels in train_dataloader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            imgs = imgs.cuda()
            labels = labels.cuda()
            y_pred = model(imgs)
            loss = criterion(y_pred, labels)
            loss.backward()

Comment: @Terrance I use instructions https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.7.1/wsl-user-guide/index.html and https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#pre-installation-actions

Comment: @sergzemsk Please edit the question to include any code (in Markdown code-blocks).  It is, as you might have noticed, unreadable in a comment ;-).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds done